# What is the "correct" way for handling date/time conversions for database?

Tags: php, database, date

I have a PHP site that gets date from the user in human-form (e.g. 2012-10-18 or some such) and stores them in a database. In the database they are stored as unix timestamps. I can either use PHP functions to do the converting, and just store/retrieve the timestamps, or I can use SQL/database functions to do the converting in the query, and store/retrieve the formatted date.
Is there a reason to prefer one method over the other? Is one of these more "correct" (separation of concerns etc.)?

Comment: I personally will rely on database function conversion, it is someway faster and produces less overhead in your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that trying to handle user timezones was complicated in SQL (at least in SQLite, not sure if other databases have better timezone support in their date functions), so PHP seems to be the better place to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Use dates in your database. The database is able to calculate with even, therefore there is no reason to do this type of handling in your PHP script. Maybe if you don't want to this, a valid argument might be because your queries are becoming a bit more complex because of the logic in it.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO there is no difference between these two methods in terms of performance, but converting/formatting sql-dates with PHP gives advantages of cleaner code and of localization ability.